# Writing to "~/Library/Application Support" folder in Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: cocoa

I can use NSFileManager to create a XYZ folder in "/Library/Application Support" in Mac OS X 10.5 and 10.6.  However, in 10.7, it says "You don't have permission to save XYZ in the folder 'Application Support'".

Does anyone know what I can do (e.g. which API to call) to get that permission to create the folder?  Thanks.

Comment: What, specifically, says that? Is it a dialog box? Message in your debugger console? Please edit your question to include either a screenshot or the full, exact text of the message.

Comment: It's in the debugger console.  The full exact text of the message is "You don't have permission to save "MacroMedia" in the folder 'Application Support'".  I'm creating "/Library/Application Support/MacroMedia/FlashPlayerTrust" (if it doesn't exist) because to embed and run a local Flash app within my WebView, I need to write a file into FlashPlayerTrust that tells Flash runtime to trust Flash apps residing in a certain directory; thus granting them permissions to run locally.

Comment: Indeed you don't. I don't think that would have worked on earlier versions of the OS, either; perhaps you were running as an admin user then and now are not? Non-admin users can't write to /Library. You'll need to create an Installer package that does that, or else have the fun times of figuring out the Good and Proper Way to do this with root powers using Authorization Services.

Comment: I'm using Admin account for 10.7, as well as on 10.5 and 10.6.  I've used Authorization Services for Login Items before; guess I've to do it in this case as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using sandboxing? If so, you’re writing to the wrong place. In either case, you should be using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` to find the right path rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: I'm not using sandboxing to limit my application in anyway.  The path is correct, but I can't write to it due to permission issues.  Thanks.

Comment: NSFileManager provides a URL-based method for the same purpose. Like its path-based function cousin, it also unlocks the returned location for use by a sandboxed app.

Comment: The problem with a path is that the resulting string sometimes just gets appended to the current folder (relative path) while the URL version below always is correct. I ended up with something like
`/Users/[user]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[AppName]-fwjsznssheiagwbotndtsnpgcrte/Build/Products/Debug/~/Library/Application Support/com.acme.[AppName]`

Answer (score 8):

As of OS X 10.6 or later, the recommended API to find the user's application support folder is:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *appSupportDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", appSupportDir);
// file://localhost/Users/abhi/Library/Application%20Support/
```

The path is not always `~/Library/Application Support`. Sometimes it's somewhere else (eg, when your app is running in a sandbox). Also, the Application Support directory might not exist yet. The above code will handle that and create it for you.

If the URL returned by that API is not writable, then you should log an exception to standard error, and allow your app to crash. This should only happen if the user has run out of disk space or something similar (in that case, it probably returns nil and an error object).

Comment: Paths can act surprising while URL's always work like intended. Use URL's when given the choice.

Comment: I’m not sure I agree with you on that - paths are simple while URLs are extremely complicated. Simple is generally better but paths are lacking some important features in this case, meaning URLs are the better choice. I personally convert URLs to paths when simplicity and predictability are critical.