# Is it possible to copy file to Main bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-copying, mainbundle

I want to copy file(image,mp3...) from main bundle to main bundle. To use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"copyname" ofType:@"mp3"]
```

`from path = /var/mobile/Applications/62734FAF-1E94-4792-9978-exam/myproject.app/file.mp3`

`to path = /var/mobile/Applications/62734FAF-1E94-4792-9978-exam/myproject.app/copyname.mp3`

`function = copyItemAtPath`

But i got the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this for iOS or OSX?

Comment: @rmaddy I think it's for iOS, since the path he provides is /var/mobile/Applications(...)

Comment: @Thedude Good point. I should have looked at that more closely.

Comment: @Sean In iOS, the main bundle is read-only on a real iOS device. You can't copy a file into the resource bundle.

Comment: No you cannot do this.  Explain why you want to do it.

Comment: Thank you guys. anyway Is there anyway to play APNS sound from Documents folder? I think APNS sound is played from main bundle if there is the sound file matched in it.

Answer (score 2):

Bundles are read-only, it's not possible to write to them.

There are, however, many places where you can store your data.
You can use the [Application Support Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185813/writing-to-library-application-support-folder-in-mac-os-x-10-7), or for temporary data you can also use the `NSTemporaryDirectory()` function to get a temporary directory.

This will also work in sandboxed applications.

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"FileNameToBeCopied" ofType:@"mp3"]
                     toPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewFileName.mp3"] error:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. I already tried it.  the same error code " The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" ...